# Sending Messages to Discussion on Telegram Channel

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I currently have a telegram channel linked to a telegram group. As a normal user, in the telegram channel, there is an option for me to "Leave a Comment", which allows me to go to the linked group to post something. How do I get my telegram bot to do this instead (i.e. leave a comment in the discussion for the post on the telegram group)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `reply_to_message_id`.

For example (`for node-telegram-bot-api`):

```
bot.sendMessage(channelDiscussId, text, {reply_to_message_id: msgId});
```

`msgId` - a ID message from discuss chat, not main chat.